# Url from JSON is showing as undefined (ReactJs)!

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was following on this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ZTT9kw3PIE&t=0s&list=PLkbmdtbypn7TwufH3veAJ6dweRvTw57tO&index=4) when I came accross an issue.
I am trying to load an image from a url which is in a JSON format.
I followed the tutorial properly but I cannot get the image to load.

Using the react-tools I saw that the url field is showing as undefined!

Here's the code:

//this is the flat.js

```
import React from 'react';
import "./flat.css";

class Flat extends React.Component {
 render() {

    const title = this.props.flat.price + this.props.flat.priceCurrency + "-" +  this.props.flat.name;
    const style  = {
        backgroundImage: `url('${this.props.flat.imageUrl}')`        
    };
    return (

     <div className="flat">
      <div className="flat-picture" style={style}></div>
      <div className="flat-title">{title}</div>

     </div>
    );
}}export default Flat;
```

//this is the app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Flat from './components/flat';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
       const flat = {
           "name": "Trendy Apt in Buttes Montmartre",
           "imageUrl": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lewagon/flats-
                        boilerplate/master/images/flat2.jpg",
           "price": 200,
           "priceCurrency": "EUR",
    };

return (
  <div>
   <Flat flat={flat} />
  </div>

); }}export default App;
```

Comment: you are passing `Flat` `"imageUrl"` as a prop but in `Flat` you reference `this.props.imgUrl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a misspelling there.

In app you have

"**imageUrl**": "flat2.jpg",

While you are using

${this.props.flat.**imgUrl**}

One is imageURL the other is imgUrl.  You need to correct.  You might also have another issue elsewhere but try correcting this.

Comment: The url is showing now but the image is still not loading

Comment: You also have a space after the flats-.  However, that might just be what you posted here and not in your code.

Comment: which flats are you referring to?

Comment: You have a space in the imageURL.  It might only be how you pasted here but the new line is a space on this example you posted. 
 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lewagon/flats-
                        boilerplate/master/images/flat2.jpg

Comment: oh thats just what i posted here

Comment: Glad that the URL is now showing, so just do a console.log of this.props.flat.imgURL to see what it says.

Comment: Ok I figured out that my flat.css file is not being loaded!Any guesses on how to fix it! The flat.css file sets a height to the flat-picture div which is 0px without it.

Comment: You are already including it, which should work unless it is in a different directory.  import "./flat.css";

Answer (score 0):

Here you are setting

> backgroundImage: url('${`this.props.flat.imgUrl`}')

In your flat object, you have.

```
flat = {
           "name": "Trendy Apt in Buttes Montmartre",
           "imageUrl": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lewagon/flats-
                        boilerplate/master/images/flat2.jpg",
           "price": 200,
           "priceCurrency": "EUR",
    };
```

I don't know if there is a type error. But, it's not. you see that you save an `a` and `e` letter

- Correct sentence

  > backgroundImage: url('${`this.props.flat.imageUrl`}')

With the image try to..

```
let variable = this.props.flat.imageUrl.toString()

const style  = {
        backgroundImage: url(variable)        
    };
```

Maybe, in that way it takes the url image. Good Luck!!

Comment: this does fix the url issue but the image is still not loading

Comment: ok. I also had my doubts about that, I was not sure about if you made a mistake typing the issue or that is the way your code looks like. I ask you, the URL value is still `undefined`?

Comment: Ok, perfect. Now,  I think at this line `'${this.props.flat.imageUrl}'`, it is taking the ` ${this.props.flat.imageUrl}` code as a string. i suggest you save the result of `this.props.flat.imageUrl` as a string in a variable and then set it to your code as `url(variable)`

Comment: Ok I figured out that my flat.css file is not being loaded!Any guesses on how to fix it! The flat.css file sets a height to the flat-picture div which is 0px without it.

Comment: Ok, I saw your post and that's right. You seem pretty new on this. Good Luck, remember to vote the correct answer for your question

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer guys !

I had simply forgotten to use the . in the css

eg:

//wrong

```
flat{
 height: 200px;
}
```

//correct

```
.flat{
 height: 200px;
}
```

Thank you guys for all your help!